# Spring transaction spanning multiple web services

Tags: spring, spring-transactions, distributed-transactions, java-transaction-service

Here is a portion of our code

```
@Transactional
public void createAccount(){
    // db call on dao to insert data at TBL_ACCOUNT
    // web service call on insertUserInfo() method of UsersWebservice

}
```

In the code of UsersWebService:

```
public void insertUserInfo() {
      //check if user account record is already inserted in TBL_ACCOUNT
      // if yes - insert data in TBL_USER_INFO, else throw exception
}
```

Since the data insert in TBL_ACCOUNT is not yet committed, insertUserInfo method of UserswebService will always throw an exception, which shouldn't be since technically, there is already inserted data in TBL_ACCOUNT, its just not committed yet.

Is there a way to deal with this scenario?

by the way we are using Spring transaction version 4.2.4.RELEASE

Comment: As a part of `createAccount()`  you are already inserting the user. Then why to check if the user got inserted or not. Looks like you can remove that check and proceed?

Comment: its a business rule that it really needs to be checked